# To change name of a discord voicechannel

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to change the name of my discord server but I am unsure how to perform such action.

Here is my full code so far:

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from string import digits, ascii_letters

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("It's ready")


@bot.command()
async def change(ctx):
    channel = 203487901092817113
    ctx.message.channel.edit(name="hello")


bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `await` keyword.

`await ctx.message.channel.edit(name="hello")`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a voice channel can be done with `guild.create_voice_channel`

```
await guild.create_voice_channel("voice channel",overwrites=None, category="category",reason=None)
```

```
voice_channel= client.get_channel(11123323002020)
await voice_channel.edit(name=f"This is a voice")
```

Editing is the exact same as with a message channel, instead get the id of the voice channel, and run the command, it gets/finds the specified channel and will make an edit.

**Channel edits are rate limited to 2 request per 5 min**